# Use Firebase-query to get data from an array of ID's

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-polymer, polymerfire

I'm trying to use Polymerfire's firebase-query to retrieve a list of children for each ID in an array. I have and array with three ID's and a firebase-query that looks like:

```
<firebase-query id="teamContacts"
                path= "{{teamConPath}}"
                data="{{teamConData}}"></firebase-query>
```

and a couple observers that look like:

```
teamConData: {
  observer: '_teamConDataChanged'
},
teamConPath: {
  value: '',
  observer: '_teamConPathChanged'
},

_teamConPathChanged: function(newValue, oldValue) {
  var self = this;
  if (!app.isEmpty(newValue)) {
    this.$.teamContacts.getStoredValue(newValue).then((response) => {
      // self.teamConData = value;
      console.log('in the gsv then');
    });
    console.log('teamConData: ', this.teamConData);
  }
},
_teamConDataChanged: function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log('teamConChanged', newValue);
},
```

Initially the path to `teamContacts` is null. After I set the path I don't understand how to get and work with the data. The Firebase documentation shows a method called `getStoredValue()` but that method doesn't seem to be present in the firebase-query source on Github. I thought setting a new path would fetch the data and trigger the observer for the data but that doesn't seem to be the case. How can I get the firebase-query to re-query with the new path and then asynchronously work with the data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know firebase at all, but a quick look at the docs implies it returns a promise of getting the value.  So at the point where you `console.log` teamConData it hasn't yet resolved (ie hasn't fetched the data).  Where you added the comment `//self.teamConData` is where the query should have populated the teamData.  As you are using ES6 arrow functions, the `this` value should be correct - so `this.teamConData` should have the data in it at that point.

Answer (score 0):

As `teamConData` it's an object I will create an observer like

```
observers: ['_teamConDataObserver(teamConData.*)'],
_teamConDataObserver: function(changedData) {
    // do something with the data
}
```

I will recommend you to look at this polycast, it could be helpful https://youtu.be/m1hFhDYDY6o?t=4m35s