# Ordering/filtering Firebase query from an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase, I have a "users" node where each user has values (name, avatar, etc) stored under their UID:

```
"users" : {
    "eMKRoygZUJZ9VFMHzzO15tnrtYf2" : {
      "gender" : "female",
      "handle" : "sav",
      "name" : "Savina",
      "profilePicture" : "https://graph.facebook.com/*removed*/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1",
    }
```

Now I need to fetch info for a specific set of users - I have an array of the UIDs of all the users that I want to fetch data for (`returnedParticipants`). Currently, the function below returns the values of ALL users in the app - I'm wondering how to filter this request so I query only the users whose UIDs are in the `returnedParticipants` array, so I can set their values accordingly to some dictionaries:

```
var returnedParticipants = [String]()

// [UID : value]
var avatarDictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [:] 
var nameDictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
var genderDictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [:]

func getParticipantInfo() {

    // Participant UIDs
    guard let participantUIDs = self.returnedParticipants as? [String] else {print("Could not get room's participants"); return}
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    // Query Firebase users with those UIDs & grab their gender, profilePicture, handle, and name
    databaseRef.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict {

                let keys  = each.key
                let avatars = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                let genders = each.value["gender"] as! String
                let handles = each.value["handle"] as! String
                let names = each.value["name"] as! String

                print("\n\nUID: \(keys)")
                print("Avatar: \(avatars)")
                print("Gender: \(genders)")
                print("Handle: \(handles)")
                print("Name: \(names)")
            }
        }
    }, withCancel: {(Err) in
        print(Err.localizedDescription)
    })

    // Set those to the dictionaries [UID : value]


}
```

I searched and saw this question on SO: [Use Firebase-query to get data from an array of ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940946/use-firebase-query-to-get-data-from-an-array-of-ids), but I'm not familiar with that language. I've looked at this page of the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data and couldn't find anything about performing queries for a list of keys.

I can use `queryOrdered(byChild: *someUID*)` if I wanted to search for one specific UID at a time, but that will involve having several calls to Firebase.

Is there an efficient way to get it all done in one call/one function instead of making a separate observe for each UID? Perhaps a way to use `queryEqualToValue` or queryStarting/Ending at value, from the array or UIDs?

Full DB structure:

```
{
"rooms" : {
    "-Ki6fAHv6LS5pyx34nUr" : {
      "messages" : {
        "-Ki70oJOAsto1uIxJsLY" : {
          "senderId" : "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53",
          "senderName" : "Timothy",
          "text" : "Test"
        }
      },
      "participants" : {
        "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : true
      },
      "roomName" : "Room One"
    },
    "-Ki6fDsTUTdNAw8elnP9" : {
      "participants" : {
        "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : true
      },
      "roomName" : "Room Two"
    },
    "-KiBBeexijDJri_w7fye" : {
      "participants" : {
        "eMKRoygZUJZ9VFMHzzO15tnrtYf2" : true
      },
      "roomName" : "Room Three"
    }
  },
"users" : {
   "eMKRoygZUJZ9VFMHzzO15tnrtYf2" : {
      "gender" : "female",
      "handle" : "sav",
      "name" : "Savina",
      "profilePicture" : "https://graph.facebook.com/1929991317219760/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"
    },
    "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : {
      "gender" : "male",
      "handle" : "TestHandleOne",
      "name" : "Timothy",
      "profilePicture" : "https://graph.facebook.com/1682119565138679/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the significance of the UIDs that you are trying to query? queryStarting/Ending will only work if the UIDs you need are in order. Since UIDs tend to me random, that probably doesn't have the desired effect. If this is a specific list that you will be querying more than once, like members of a group, you should denormalize the data so that you can query the group you're looking for. [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) can tell you a bit about that. Otherwise, there is no way to query a random assortment of UIDs as a single query.

Comment: It is a group of users, it's a group chat so my array is a list of the UIDs of the people that are "in" that chat room. Like the people in a group chat in iMessage or WhatsApp. People can be added or removed from the room, and that array of participants is updated when that happens.... If I'm understanding correctly from that link, I'll need to add a third node (I already have "users" and "rooms") called "groups"?

Comment: Exactly! That seems like the perfect time to use denormalization. As users enter the chat, you can add and remove their uid from the child node for that chat room. Depending on what data you need about each user, you may be able to use a Cloud Function that triggers when a child is added to the chat room node that reads the user's info from the "users" child. But you can always start by handling all the work client-side.

Comment: I see. So for example when a user is added to a chat, currently I just add their UID to a "participants" node within the room that they are added to. So the better approach would be to also add their UID to that room's subnode within "groups" (that I guess should have the same ID as the chat)?

Comment: Well, it really depends on what information you are looking to query. It sounds like you have this group chat and you require more data about the users than just the uid. You can include the necessary data in the participants node if it's data you'll require every time you make that query. Otherwise, you can have a separate node that you query when you need that info, or have a separate query for each participating user in the users node. A Cloud Function can handle writing and removing data from multiple locations in the database outside the client, making it easier to denormalize.

Comment: To put it simply: there is no perfect answer. The method that works best is unique to each app. In this case, it seems like you should focus more on the structure of the database so that you can download only the data you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I guess I'll have to weigh my options and look into adding a groups node in my database. The data that I need from each user will be the same every time that chat is loaded (I'll always need each user's name, avatar, etc). But then (if I choose to keep each user's info, as well as their UID, within that room's "participants" in the database), I'll have each user, and all their information, scattered around the database a few times - once in the "users" node as seen in my question, then again within the "participants" node of each chat they're a part of.

Comment: I put my full database structure in my question in case I'm not making any sense describing what it looks like (sorry about the formatting).. but thanks for your suggestions, it sounds like adding a "groups" node may be the way to go.